# Reverse for 'ingredient-list' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 11}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['inventory/ingredients/\\Z']

Tags: html

I'm new to Django and programming in general. I'm going through the book Django For Beginners and have added my own flair in the forms section but have run into a problem. Below I have detailed the error and provided my code.
Reverse for 'ingredient-list' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 11}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['inventory/ingredients/\Z']
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/inventory/ingredients/add_ingredient/
Django Version: 5.0.3
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'ingredient-list' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 11}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['inventory/ingredients/\Z']
Exception Location: C:\Users\manoj\OneDrive\Desktop\Djnago_Delights_Resturant\myenv\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 851, in _reverse_with_prefix

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    ingredient_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient_name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('ingredient-list', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *



urlpatterns = [
    path('home/',HomePage.as_view(),name='home'),
    path('ingredients/', InventoryListView.as_view(), name='ingredient-list'),
    path('ingredient/<int:pk>/delete/', InventoryDeleteView.as_view(), name='ingredient-delete'),
    path('menu/', MenuDetailsView.as_view(), name='menu-list'),
    path('purchases/', PurchasesListView.as_view(), name='purchase-list'),
    path('profit/', ProfitView.as_view(), name='profit'),

    path('ingredients/add_ingredient/', AddIngredientFormView.as_view(),name='add-ingredient'),
    path('ingredients/add_menuitem/',AddMenuItem.as_view(),name='add-menuitem'),
    path('ingredients/add_recipe_requirement/',RecipeRequirementFormView.as_view(),name='add-recipe'),
    path('menu/purchases/',AddPurchasesFormView.as_view(),name='add-purchases')
]
```

Views.py

```
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper, DecimalField
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import ListView, TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView, CreateView

from .forms import IngredientForm, MenuItemForm, RecipeRequirementForm, PurchasesForm
from .models import Ingredient, CustomerPurchases, MenuItem, RecipeRequirement


# Create your views here.
class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'inventory/home.html'


class InventoryListView(ListView):
    model = Ingredient
    template_name = 'inventory/ingredient_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'ingredients'


class AddIngredientFormView(CreateView):
    model = Ingredient
    form_class = IngredientForm
    template_name = 'inventory/add_ingredient.html'


class InventoryDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Ingredient
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ingredient-list')


class PurchasesListView(ListView):
    model = CustomerPurchases
    template_name = 'inventory/purchases.html'
    context_object_name = 'purchases'


class AddPurchasesFormView(CreateView):
    model = CustomerPurchases
    form_class = PurchasesForm
    template_name = 'inventory/add_purchases.html'


class MenuDetailsView(ListView):
    model = MenuItem
    template_name = 'menuitem_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'menuitems'


class AddMenuItem(CreateView):
    model = MenuItem
    form_class = MenuItemForm
    template_name = 'inventory/add_menuitem.html'


class ProfitView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'inventory/profitandrevenue.html'  # Template to render the profit

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # Calculate total revenue
        total_revenue = CustomerPurchases.objects.aggregate(total_revenue=Sum('price'))['total_revenue']

        # Calculate total cost
        total_cost = RecipeRequirement.objects.annotate(
            total_cost=ExpressionWrapper(F('quantity') * F('ingredient__unit_price'), output_field=DecimalField())
        ).aggregate(total_cost=Sum('total_cost'))['total_cost']

        # Calculate profit
        profit = total_revenue - total_cost if total_cost else 0

        context['profit'] = profit
        return context


class RecipeRequirementFormView(CreateView):
    model = RecipeRequirement
    form_class = RecipeRequirementForm
    template_name = 'inventory/add_reciperequirement.html'
```

add_ingredint.html

```
{% extends 'inventory/base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Add Ingredient | Django Delights
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="card-title text-center mb-4">Add Ingredient To Database</h3>
          <form method="post" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p}}
            <div class="text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Ingredient</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```